# Treat error when when key does not exist

Tags: meteor, spacebars

How can one make spacebars react when the set key does not exist in the template?

Example:

```
//JavaScript
Template.foo.helpers({
    //"zaz" : "hello",
    "bar" : 1
});
```

...

```
<!-- Template -->
<template name="foo">  
  {{bar}}
  {{#ifExist zaz}}
      {{zaz}}
  {{else}} 
      "fill-me" 
  {{/ifExist}} 
</template>
```

Comment: Strongly smells like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What's your use-case? Why would you try to call functions that may not exist? If it is to leave blatant `TODO`s in your code (with the "fill me"), then why not coding the method and logging/returning "[SomeMethod] has not been implemented!"

Comment: I agree with your observation, in case it was needed because it had no control of the fields that would be exposed in "helpers". The more correct yet I would have put this question using UI.registerHelper, but this really does not run if the element does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just check if your helper is defined by using a simple `if` statement followed by the helper or value you want to check:

```
<template name="foo">  
  {{bar}}
  {{#if zaz}}
      {{zaz}}
  {{else}}
      fill-me
  {{/if}} 
</template>
```